# Is there a way to match options behind references in Rust?

Tags: rust

If I have a struct that is something along the lines of:

```
struct Thing {
    opt: Option<Box<u32>>
}
fn main() {
    let thing = Thing{opt:Some(Box::new(5))};
    let pointer = &thing;
    match pointer.opt {
        None => println!("There is nothing"),
        Some(thing) => println!("There is a thing {}", thing)
    }
}
```

I get an error along the lines of: "cannot move out of 'pointer.opt' as enum variant 'Some' which is behind a shared reference"
Could someone please explain why this error happens and potential ways around it?

The thing I am working on requires working with a reference to a struct with a similar option in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`std::option::Option::as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) for exactly this kind of situation:

```
match pointer.opt.as_ref() {
    None => println!("There is nothing"),
    Some(thing) => println!("There is a thing {}", thing)
}
```

Comment: Does `match &pointer.opt` accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @user229044 yes, but not quite for the same reasons. If it works, it's because of some conveniences `match` provides. [Adding a `ref` in the pattern](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c003344813c0c974503a3cd506f289e0) also works.